# How to make my Query like this using array and implode?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, sql-insert

```
$data = array('Cardinal', 'Tom B.','tom@email.com');
$stmt = mysqli_prepare("INSERT INTO $table  (username,password,email) VALUES ($data)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you out. Here we are appending single quotes at the starting and ending of string of `$data` array and then imploding that array with `,`

```
<?php

$data = array('Cardinal', 'Tom B.','tom@email.com');
//adding single quotes
$data=array_map(function($value){
    return $value="'$value'";
}, $data);
//imploding array with ,
$data=  implode(",", $data);
echo $query="INSERT INTO $table  (username,password,email) VALUES ($data)";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($query);
```

**Output:** `of echo $query;`

```
INSERT INTO   (username,password,email) VALUES ('Cardinal','Tom B.','tom@email.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is this:

```
$data = implode("','", ['Cardinal', 'Tom B.', 'tom@email.com']);
$stmt = mysqli_prepare(
    "INSERT INTO $table (username,password,email) VALUES ('$data')"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
"INSERT INTO $table (username,password,email) VALUES ('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]')"
```